# Connecting from Tableau Desktop to Apache Hive

Tags: hive, desktop, tableau-api

When testing the connection from Tableau Desktop to Apache Hive Server, it throws an error that the drivers have not be installed. Tableau is providing [drivers](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers) for only Cloudera, HortonWorks and MapR. But, the drivers are not provided for Apache Hive.

How to connect to from Tableau Desktop to Apache Hive?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the MapR driver.

Reference http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+ODBC+Connector#HiveODBCConnector-InstallingtheHiveODBCConnectoronWindows